# Linear-interpolation function for missing values

Tags: python-3.x, data-science

I'm new to python programming and I want to try writing a linear-interpolation function for missing values. For example

```
Day    Value1   Value2
1       50       30
2       Nan      Nan
3       Nan      10
4       30       Nan
```

I want to calculate Nan in day 2 and 3 using python for example?

Comment: I'd recommend using the pandas library. Once you have your data in a dataframe you can simply use df.interpolate().

Comment: But how it works if I want to calculate missing data for different missing days.?

Comment: You can fill in missing days by using the .resample method beforehand.